# Edge detection from Google Earth basemap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, google-earth, boundaries, edge-detection

I would like to detect boundaries of agricultural fields for 70 different polygons spread out across a country.
Is it possible to run an edge detection algorithm using the google earth (or equivalent) basemap in QGIS to avoid having to download many separate satellite imagery files?